# Relationship between CO2 concentration and thermal conductivity of the air in a volume?

Tags: atmospheric-science, air, thermal-conductivity

How much would the percentage of CO2 in a room need to change in order to make a measurable change (using transient hot wire method) to the thermal conductivity of the air inside room? Are there other changes to the air composition that could drive a significant change in the thermal conductivity?

Thermal conductivity just happens to be the easiest air parameter for me to instrument, I'm looking for ways to modify the air in a sealed space and then sense  when the space becomes open by measuring the conductivity (or whatever else will do it) as it equalise with the bulk atmosphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think you can get enough CO2 into room air to have a signal and still breathe it.

Humidity might be a much stronger signal. Particularly at just above room temperature, the thermal conductivity varies significantly with humidity:

[image]

(From [here](https://www.electronics-cooling.com/2003/11/the-thermal-conductivity-of-moist-air/), which has more info)